# Changing collection path and index path in mongod.conf file

Tags: mongodb-3.6

I want to have collection path and index path in different folders of my mongodb.
What are the required changes? My current configuration file is this:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /db/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
```

How can I give index path and collection path? Can anyone give me an example?